# Did Abraham Lincoln kill the man who murdered his mother?

Tags: abraham-lincoln

I'm watching a dramatized (re-enacted) biography of Abraham Lincoln and it shows him as having shot a man in the eye, shortly after the death of Lincoln's father. The man apparently had something to do with the death of Lincoln's mother, though I'm a bit fuzzy on the details.

Is this supported by fact, or is it speculation / fiction?

Comment: Which bio pic are you watching?

Comment: @Schwern It's called "Abraham Licoln: Vampire Hunter"

Comment: I suspected it might be. He didn't fight vampires either. Just making sure we make that clear. ;)

Comment: @Schwern Heh. Well I just thought that *some* of it might've been true lol.

Comment: Did you do any preliminary research? [Lincoln's mother died from drinking bad milk](http://rogerjnorton.com/Lincoln81.html).  I don't know if Lincoln killed the cow.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Yes, I watched the movie and I Googled it but there seemed to be conflicting information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abraham Lincoln's birth mother, [Nancy Lincoln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Lincoln), died when Abraham was 9 of either [milk sickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_sickness) or possibly [consumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumption_(disease)). Milk sickness is from drinking milk contaminated with the poison [tremetol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremetol) by the cows eating [snakeroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageratina_altissima). Two other people on the Lincoln's property also died of milk sickness. I can find no suggestion of foul play.

After Nancy died his father Thomas Lincoln married [Sarah Bush Lincoln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Bush_Lincoln). She lived until 1869 outliving both Thomas and Abraham.

I also cannot find mention of Abraham shooting anyone, in the eye or otherwise. It is possible he shot someone during his stint as a Captain during the [Black Hawk War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hawk_War), but that would be 20 years before his father died.

Comment: I wonder if Pasteurization would've prevented her death

Comment: @Hack-R [Nope](https://www.addl.purdue.edu/newsletters/2004/winter/finaldx.asp).

Comment: @Hack-R: No, the toxin is not affected by pasteurization; but modern husbandry practices dramatically reduce incidence by (i) controlling the forage of livestock; and (ii) by pooling milk among from many animals before bottling any toxin in the supply is diluted to much less dangerous levels.